# Azure DevOps VSTest@2 isn't finding the correct test .dll to execute tests against

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following .yml configuration to run my automated tests.

```
pool:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest

steps:
- script: set
  displayName: print all variables
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**\*.sln'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Set Sauce Environment Variables'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./setEnvironmentVariables.ps1
    arguments: '$env:sauce_userName sauce_accessKey $env:SAUCE_RDC_VODQANATIVEAPPAPIKEY $env:SAUCE_RDC_SauceDemoIosRdcApiKey'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run Best Practices Framework'
  inputs:
    #testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    #testAssemblyVer2: '**/*Selenium3.Nunit.Framework*'
    testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=BestPractices'
    runInParallel: true
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    testRunTitle: 'NUnit Automation Framework'
    rerunFailedTests: true
    rerunFailedThreshold: 10
    rerunMaxAttempts: 2
    failOnMinTestsNotRun: true
```

I notice that in the logs that the only executables that are being checked for tests are in this folder `D:\a\1\s\SauceExamples\packages\` which isn't correct.

As a result, I keep getting the following message `NUnit couldn't find any tests in D:\a\1\s\SauceExamples\packages\`

How can I make the `VSTest@2` actually look in the correct .dll for automated tests?

Locally, the path of that .dll looks like this:
`C:\Source\SauceLabs\demo-csharp\SauceExamples\Web.Tests\bin\Debug\Selenium3.Nunit.Framework.dll`

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for the VSTest task? The documentation will show you how to change the search path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test files format should look like `testAssemblyVer2: '**\*test*.dll'`, so you may
try the following format:

`testAssemblyVer2: '**\Selenium3.Nunit.Framework.dll'`